# Did Twitter discontinue API that broadcoasts tweets based on search tags?

Tags: ajax, jquery, twitter

I'm trying to display tweets coming from search tags and not by user, but couldn't get a result :(

**http://jsfiddle.net/YS3u4/89/**

Note: **http://jsfiddle.net/YS3u4/90/** this doesn't work either.

```
var tag = "weather";
$.getJSON("https://twitter.com/search/tweets/" + tag + "?count=5&format=json&callback=?", function(data) {
      $.each(data, function (index, item) {
          $("<li/>").html(item.text).appendTo("#output");
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The codes are fine. **The problem is coming from Twitter's side.** The sample link written in their API 1.1 documentation (the one that is searching for superbowl) is also throwing error.